# Javascript hides jquery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have an iOS-like folder in my website in javascript. there's some html forms inside the folder (meaning that you can see the form only after you open the folder). Also, i'm trying to implement jquery datepicker inside the folder, but it doesn't work probably because of the the folder javascript code that hides the folder contents when the page loads. I'm not that proficient in javascript so I would be really gratefull if someone points me on how to modify the code for the datepicker to work.

here's the iOS-like folder js code :

```
$(function() {
$(".folderContent").hide();

//arrange the background image starting position for all the rows.
//This will allow the background image cut illusion when showing the folder content panel
$(".row").each(function() {

});

//when a folder is clicked,
//position the content folder after the clicked row
//and toggle all folder / app icon that is not the one clicked.
//and toggle the folder content panel
$(".folder").click(function(event) {

    var folderContent = $(".folderContent");
    folderContent.remove();

    var folderContentShown = folderContent.css("display") != "none";

    var clickedFolder = $(this);
    clickedFolder.parent(".row").after(folderContent);

    folderContent.find(".folderName").html( );

    $("body").find(".folder, .app").not(clickedFolder).each(function() {
        if (!folderContentShown) $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.00
        }, "slow");
        else $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1.00
        }, "slow");
    });

    //clickedFolder.animate({opacity: folderContentShown ? 1.00 : 0.70}, "slow");
    folderContent.slideToggle("slow");
    event.preventDefault();
    });
    });
```

and here's the datepicker code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
$.extend($.datepicker.regional["ru"])
);
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

If i remove the iOS-like js code - the datepicker works fine, so it's definitely a problem with the iOS-like code.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

the last file included in html (slide.js) is the code that is at the top of the post. full html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="slide.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.csss" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table class='buttons_table'>

<tr><td>
<div class='row2'>
<div class='folder2'><span class='button gray medium'>xxxx</span></div>
</div>
</td></tr>

</table>

<div class='folder2Content'><span class='folder2Name'>

<form action='xxx.php' method='post'>
<table class='input_text'>
<tr>
<td>date : </td>
<td>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
$.extend($.datepicker.regional["ru"])
);
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="year" />
</td>
</tr></div></span></table>
```

Comment: could you also post your HTML code?

Comment: sure, updated the first post.

Comment: I think you have some discrepancy in your code. I have set up a jsfiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/william/qfXKb/1/. could you make the code more like what you have? You can include more js/css files from "Manage Resources" section at the left. Or simply paste them in the appropriate window.

Comment: hey, done as requested - http://jsfiddle.net/qfXKb/18/ - for now you see when you click xxxx button the date section slides out and does not show you the calendar when you click in the input form :( but if in the js code you will change     $(".folderContent").hide(); to     $(".folderContent").show(); everything is going to work, but i need the slider to be closed when the page loads. This is exactly what my problem is as i want the calendar (and basically any other javascript i will put inside the slider in future) to work properly within the slider.

Comment: Glad to be helpful! As a custom in Stack Overflow (SO), if you think an answer satisfied your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer. This would help the later-comers to know this question is solved. For each answer, you can also cast an upvote if you think it is useful, or a downvote if you think it is incorrect or deviates too much from the question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why when you hide the area, datepicker no longer works is because you no only hide it, but actually remove it from the DOM tree. even though you later add it back in, all the attached events and data are lost in the process. Fortunately jQuery can actually accommodate this with the `.detach()` function. So, instead of using `.remove()`, you can use `.detach()` instead to retain the attached events and data.

```
folderContent.detach();
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/qfXKb/21/.